# jquery same selector for multiple contexts

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want wrote a elegant solution that select a same tag by searching in
a list of different contexts

```
//i have this not editable code
var c1$ = $('#context1'),
    c2$ = $('#context2'),
    c3$ = $('#context3');

//I want to improve the code and 'only from here on
var selector = 'a.select';
c1$.find(selector).css('color','red');
c3$.find(selector).css('color','red');
```

I'm searching a solution for arbitrary number of contexts

Answer (score 8):

You can use `$.add()` to build up your context, and then use it as a single jQuery object within the context parameter of your selector:

```
var $foo = $("#foo"),
    $bar = $("#bar");

var $context = $foo.add($bar);

$("a.select", $context).css("color", "red");
```

Comment: @StefanoCudini Updated the answer per your comments.

Comment: good idea! but my real problem is that i have the contexts selectors into a variables
See my code edit above please

Comment: well thanks, I was trying this solution right now and I was wondering if it can aggregate any number of contexts included in an array

Comment: `$foo.add($bar).add($fiz).add($buz)`. You can add as many as you like.

Comment: i want a similiar idea:

 var selector = 'a.select';
 $([c1$,c3$]).find(selector).css('color','red');

but this code il bad!

Comment: i already thought about loop solution, but I want to leave it as a final solution, now I wanted to find a most elegant solution.
Another problem is that at finally i want insert matched elements into a single variable for further processing and after apply a css edit in once step

Comment: @StefanoCudini I've provided one last solution. After having edited my answer five times, I hope you find at least one of the solutions to be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't load a list of context, and then do a foreach to find the 'a.select' in each of the context?.

Comment: i already thought about this, but I want to leave it as a final solution, now I wanted to find a most elegant solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

my desperate not elegant solution

```
var contexts = [$('#context1'),$('#context2'),$('#context3')];
//list of contexts in single variable(arbitrary number!)

var selector = 'a.select';
//same selector for all variable contexts

var cons$ = $([]);
//empty temporary selector

for(i in contexts)
    cons$ = cons$.add(contexts[i]);

var allmatches$ = cons$.find(selector);

//here processing allmatches$

allmatches$.css("color", "red"); 
//now apply css in one step
```